# SumIF & Merge columns based on another column criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please find below samples, where I want to do coding for rest of my actual data set,

`ColumnA` has multiple states name, `ColumnB` has unique values, and in `columnC` we want a `sumif` of `columnB`  & `Merging cells` results based on states name (`columnA`).

```
Dim ColumnA as long
Dim ColumnC as long

ColumnsC = 0
ColumnA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).value

Lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to lastrow 
    IF Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).value = ColumnA Then    
        ColumnC = ColumnC + Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, 3).value   
    End if
Next

worksheets("sheet1").cells(2, 3).value = ColumnC
```

Comment: There is no question. Please check [ask]. Also [mcve] might help to improve your question. Please add example input data and desired output. Also explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: A pretty reliable rule of thumb: Do not merge cells. Why does a pivot table not work here?

Answer (score 1):

A pivot table does this without the need for formulas and merging cells (*which I advocate you never do on your source data sets*).

---

### Pivot Table

1. Add fields State & City to `Rows`
2. Add field Value to `Values`
3. Pivot Table Report Layout = Tabular
4. Subtotals = Off

[image]

*Raw data source on left and pivot table output on right*

Comment: i have a huge data set almost  97,000 row and 58 columns that was just part of that project hence i have shared just a sample for better understanding. and that's why i need macro Coding so i will append that codes into my actual data set codes.

Comment: That sounds like even more reasons to not merge your cells. You will find that it actually makes working with your source data harder in the future. Equations don’t like merged cells. Pivot tables were built to address this. I’d recommend rethinking your approach. You’re making your problem harder than it needs to be while changing your raw data for the worse and even harder to use later.